# Using stric / weak dominant strategy to get 2x2 matrix in Game Theory

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I've encountered a problem with a 2x3 game where I need to find Pure NE and Mix NE so I thought it's better first to get a 2x2 matrix.

For some reason I find it very difficult to solve this with strict or weak dominance.

The original matrix is as follows:

```
[4,3][5,2][2,3]
[2,0][7,2][1,3]
```

I thought maybe removing the middle column since `[4,3]` and `[2,3]` are pure strategies of NE, but I'm not sure if that is the way to go about it..

Any way I look at this, I can find the solution for a 2x2 matrix. Is there such a situation where there is no solution using strict / weak dominant?

Can you help me find a solution and the method so I can implement it in the future?